# Received NULL response code when posting data to web URL (using retrofit)

Tags: android, api, android-studio, postman, retrofit

i want to post data this json data:

```
{
 "ProductId": 182,
 "CustomerId": 1
 "sizeQuantities": [
{
  "SizeId": 1,
  "Quantity": 100
}  ]}
```

i have created model classes using this

model classes
AddCart.Java

```
public class AddCart {

@SerializedName("ProductId")
private Long mProductId;

@SerializedName("CustomerId")
private Long mCustomerId;

@SerializedName("sizeQuantities")
private List<SizeQuantity> mSizeQuantities;

public AddCart(Long mProductId, Long mCustomerId, List<SizeQuantity> mSizeQuantities) {
    this.mProductId = mProductId;
    this.mCustomerId = mCustomerId;
    this.mSizeQuantities = mSizeQuantities;
}

public Long getCustomerId() {
    return mCustomerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(Long customerId) {
    mCustomerId = customerId;
}

public Long getProductId() {
    return mProductId;
}

public void setProductId(Long productId) {
    mProductId = productId;
}

public List<SizeQuantity> getSizeQuantities() {
    return mSizeQuantities;
}

public void setSizeQuantities(List<SizeQuantity> sizeQuantities) {
    mSizeQuantities = sizeQuantities;
}}
```

and the second class is SizeQuantity.java

```
public class SizeQuantity {

@SerializedName("SizeId")
private Long mSizeId;

@SerializedName("Quantity")
private Long mQuantity;

public SizeQuantity(Long mSizeId, Long mQuantity) {
    this.mSizeId = mSizeId;
    this.mQuantity = mQuantity;
}

public Long getQuantity() {
    return mQuantity;
}

public void setQuantity(Long quantity) {
    mQuantity = quantity;
}

public Long getSizeId() {
    return mSizeId;
}

public void setSizeId(Long sizeId) {
    mSizeId = sizeId;
}}
```

activity class:

```
long ProductId = 182;
            long CustomerId = 1;
            long sizeId = 1;
            long quantity = 100;

            SizeQuantity sizeQuantity = new SizeQuantity(sizeId, quantity);

            Call<AddCart> cartCall = api.postData(sizeQuantity);
            cartCall.enqueue(new Callback<AddCart>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<AddCart> call, Response<AddCart> response) {
                    Toast.makeText(ProductDetailsActivity.this, "Code: " + response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<AddCart> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(ProductDetailsActivity.this, "onFailure" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

these piece of code i have called in on create And interface looks like this:

```
@POST("cart/AddCart")
Call<AddCart> postData(@Body SizeQuantity sizeQuantity);
```

i don't know where's the problem cause' onfailure method is not getting called on response getting called so basically inteface is right or wrong

Answer (score 1):

You need to add AddCart is post request according to your post json your are only sending sizeQuantity

```
Call<AddCart> cartCall = api.postData(sizeQuantity);
```

change to

```
Call<AddCart> cartCall = api.postData(AddCart);
```

Comment: AddCart addCart = new AddCart(ProductId, CustomerId);                                         Call<AddCart> cartCall = api.postData(addCart);

Comment: have you check the file path of server is it right? here @POST("cart/AddCart")

Comment: have to added the "/" at the end of baseUrl

Comment: no, that's fine cause i have done get method before with that url works fine!!

Comment: that is the error value have you check with debugger and also add @Expose on top of @SerializedName("") fields